# Last five digits of $2016^{{2016}^{{2016}^{2016}}}$

Tags: number-theory

> Find the last five digits of $2016^{{2016}^{{2016}^{2016}}}$ with no calculator.

We are to find the remainder, upon division by $10^5$, of $2016^{{2016}^{{2016}^{2016}}}$. Firstly note that $2016 = 2^5 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 7$. Thus, $$2016^{{2016}^{{2016}^{2016}}} = (2^5 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 7)^{{2016}^{{2016}^{2016}}}.$$ Thus, it suffices to find the remainders when $(2^5)^{{2016}^{{2016}^{2016}}},(3^2)^{{2016}^{{2016}^{2016}}},$ and $7^{{2016}^{{2016}^{2016}}}$ are divided by $10^5$.

I thought about using the Euler's Totient Theorem but that doesn't seem to help since $\phi(10^5) =\phi(2^5) \phi(5^5) =  40000$, which has a factor of $5^2$.

Answer (score 1):

notice that $\lambda(10^5)=5000,\lambda(5000)=500,\lambda(500)=100$

From here we have $2016^{2016}\equiv 16^{16}\equiv 116\bmod 500$

From here $2016^{2016^{2016}}\equiv 2016^{116}\equiv 2616 \bmod5000$

From here $2016^{2016^{2016^{2016}}}\equiv 2016^{2616}\equiv27616\bmod 10^5$

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @user19405892 For a straighter answer,the last five digits are $27616$

Comment: @tatan i think showing how I obtained the result is important.

Comment: @CarryonSmiling Ofcourse its important....but I had to make the comment seeing OP's remark that-"How does that answer the question?"....

Comment: How did you find that $16^{16} \equiv 116 \pmod{500}$?

Comment: I put it into wolframalpha

Comment: How did you calculate those values for the Carmichael function?

Comment: you use the fornula, its the lcm of the charmicael function of its prime powers

Comment: Also, $116 \pmod{500}$ doesn't necessarily imply $116 \pmod{5000}$.

Comment: Idon't know what you mean. The answer is correct. To calculate $x^a \bmod m$ you just need to know $a\bmod \lambda(m)$ (assuming $x$ is coprime with $m$)

Comment: @CarryonSmiling The question says "with no calculator", so WolframAlpha isn't allowed.